# Regex for Currency with ',' and/or '.'

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm kinda rusty with regular expressions. I need a REGEX that will validate values formatted like the following:

```
123.00
123,00
1324,00
1234.00
123
1213.0
```

I tried ^\d.\d{2}$, but it does not seem to match all values.

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Yeah, I tried ^\d\.\d{2}$, I forgot how the OR statement works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
\d+[.,]?\d+
```

Good luck!

Comment: this pattern will not match single digits

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+[,.]?\d*
```

I would strongly advise against mixing cultures especially for persistence or transport.

Answer (score 1):

The Regex you're likely looking for is something like `@"\d+([,.]\d+)?"`

It specifies "Some number of digits, optionally followed by a `.` or `,` and at least one digit". It would **not** match `123.`.

If you want to match culture-specific strings, however, I'd recommend using [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then look for that specifically.

Comment: No need to escape a dot in a character class. +1